# Published own npm react package causes project's big bundle

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have my own ui library, called `my-library` which I am using in main project.

After some optimalization I figure out, that `my-library` cause that main project's bundle is too big, approximately 9MB (even with Webpack production mode). `webpack-bundle-analyzer` shows that almost 6MB takes `react-icons` library which I am using in `my-library`. There are some other big parts, which are caused also by `my-library`.

I think that there is some problem with "esm" vs "cjs". But in that part I am stuck.

I am attaching the parts of the code that I think are relevant.

**my-library**

```
// my-library babel.config.js

module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

```
// my-library package.json

{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "3.9.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
     "build": "babel src --out-dir dist
  },
   "dependencies": {
     "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

```
// my-librabry src/index.js

export { default as CrossButton } from './components/CrossButton'

// ...
```

```
// my-library CrossButton component

import React from 'react'
import { FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa' // Webpack bundle all 'fa' icons, not just FaTimes

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const CrossButton = ({
    text=""
}) => {

    return (
        <button type="button">
         <FaTimes size={20} />
         {text}
           
        </button>
    )
}

CrossButton.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string,
}

export default Button
```

**Project**

```
// Project's Webpack config

 module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
        ]
    },
```

```
import { CrossButton } from "my-library"
```

---

Note: I would rather not bundle 'my-library'. There were some complications with Redux, or something, I don't remember.

Comment: Its' not really clear what you are asking here.  You state that your library is adding 9MB to  the project, then state that a library that you **are using** is contributing 6MB of that size, along with some other "big parts".  Are you trying to say you are expecting people to be able to use your library without adding it's size to their project??

Comment: I solved it by following tutorial https://medium.com/@LEM_ing/building-a-react-components-library-without-transpiling-8b24a1ae62a1. I don't know if publishing untraspiled code is the best approach, but it's my private package, so it doesn't matter.